How do you all make travel interesting for players?
I'm curious on how you all make travel more interesting for your players. I want to honor the geography of the world (aka you don't just teleport anywhere) and I've tried some things that have been ok, but I still don't feel like I do travel well, what do you all do?
Things I've done:
Narration of the general travel through the day, describing some key landmarks they pass.
Camp at night and let the characters just interact with each other and calling it as soon as conversation dies.
Creating some sort of urgency/task for them to make decisions on as food wanes down (for long travel)
Battle from either minor baddies or potential short encounter with a "world boss" (dragon or something that they could optionally fight, like a side boss in a video game)
Exlporation of a PCs backstory or interaction with warlock patron.
What makes travel fun for you and your players?

What game are you playing? Different ones handle it differently and some even have specific rules for what happens while traveling.

Does this answer your question: What's the best way to make time spent travelling more interesting?

@ThomasMarkov, I would say that question gives from great world building answers and gives an answer to my question. Always open to more suggestions, but my question is similar enough to collapse it into that one. Thank you!!

@JT You should now see a prompt above the question offering to close it as a duplicate.
